# ERROR: column "summed_hits" does not exist When using AS in select

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias

i have a rails app where i am trying to sum values from hstore.

This is the query:

```
# SELECT *, COALESCE(NULLIF(analytics->'2018.5.17.hits', '')::INT, 0) + COALESCE(NULLIF(analytics->'2018.5.18.hits', '')::INT, 0) + COALESCE(NULLIF(analytics->'20
18.5.19.hits', '')::INT, 0) + COALESCE(NULLIF(analytics->'2018.5.20.hits', '')::INT, 0) + COALESCE(NULLIF(analytics->'2018.5.21.hits', '')::INT, 0) + COALESCE(NULLIF(analyt
ics->'2018.5.22.hits', '')::INT, 0) + COALESCE(NULLIF(analytics->'2018.5.23.hits', '')::INT, 0) + COALESCE(NULLIF(analytics->'2018.5.24.hits', '')::INT, 0) as summed_hits F
ROM "searched_words" WHERE "searched_words"."account_id" = 2 AND (name ILIKE '%%') AND (analytics ?| ARRAY['2018.5.17.hits','2018.5.18.hits','2018.5.19.hits','2018.5.20.hit
s','2018.5.21.hits','2018.5.22.hits','2018.5.23.hits','2018.5.24.hits']) AND (summed_hits > 1) AND (analytics ?| ARRAY['2018.5.17.hits','2018.5.18.hits','2018.5.19.hits','2
018.5.20.hits','2018.5.21.hits','2018.5.22.hits','2018.5.23.hits','2018.5.24.hits']);
ERROR:  column "summed_hits" does not exist
LINE 1: ...22.hits','2018.5.23.hits','2018.5.24.hits']) AND (summed_hit...
```

I can't seem to grasp, why postgres doesn't recognize `summed_hits` from the SELECT clouse...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use alias in where, as per:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in
>   ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses, but not in the WHERE or HAVING clauses;
>   there you must write out the expression instead.

Comment: Any worarounds, so i can still implement my feature?